# Cannot do work in background periodically with alarmmanager

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-intentservice

I want to call a service in background by the hour.

first problem is alarm manager is not working smoothly. Timer is terrible, sometimes early sometimes later.

second problem is, RemoteServiceException  : Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground() , I cant understand why I get this exception

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(MainActivity.this.ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 60 * 60 * 1000L, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

AlarmReceiver

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Intent downloadService = new Intent(context, CallService.class);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            context.startForegroundService(downloadService);
        } else {
            context.startService(downloadService);
        }

    }

}
```

CallService

```
public class CallService extends IntentService {

    public CallService() {
        super("");
    }

    public CallService(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent workIntent) {
        Log.d("Now : ", Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString());



    }
}
```

Manifest

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"/>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".CallService"
            android:exported="false"/>
```

Sorry for my terrible english. Thanks for any help or suggestion.
I dont know how can I do different way. I just only call a service periodically

Comment: Try job dispatcher or job schedule instead of alarmmanager. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android . OR  https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling

Answer (score 1):

AlarmManager will be works normally on api 27 (oreo 8.1) and less. Just setup with something like that:

```
public void setupAlarm(Context context, long triggerAtMillis) {
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = getPendingIntent(context);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerAtMillis, AlarmIntentBuilder.buildPendingIntent(context, uri));
    } else if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerAtMillis, AlarmIntentBuilder.buildPendingIntent(context, uri));
    } else {
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerAtMillis, AlarmIntentBuilder.buildPendingIntent(context, uri));
    }
}
```

Don't forget that you need to setup your alarm again every time when your *AlarmReceiver* triggered. But that code will not be working on api 28 and more (pie 9.0). This is happening because of [Power management](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/power) feature introduced in Android Pie. Strict restrictions are introduced on the apps running in background. These restrictions are explained [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/power/power-details). Try to use JobScheculer to invoke your foreground IntentService.

As about your second question. You need to make a notification in your *CallService*. Just add this onCreate to your *IntentService*:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel("test", "your_channel_name", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (manager != null) {
            manager.createNotificationChannel(chan);
        }

        Notification.Builder notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(context, "test");
        notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true);
        notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("Updatig")
                .setContentText("Wait for finish updating")
        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

RemoteServiceException will be thrown if you will not call startForeground in service (you have 5 seconds to make this call) after startForegroundService.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with alarm manager.
You can switch to Interval of RxJava.

```
protected fun startCountdown(period: Long, timeUnit: TimeUnit): Observable<Long> {
        return Observable.interval(period, timeUnit)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
    }
```

usage;

```
startCountdown(MEDIA_LOCATION_CHANGE_PERIOD, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .subscribe {
            fireSomethingUp()
        }
```

Comment: After termination of application, your rxjava will not be executed. AlarmManager and rxjava interval tottaly different things, that can't be compared.

Comment: @HeyAlex You have a point. I thought he has Service and will call rest from this Service.