# Service does not execute when app is closed, but it does execute when it's in the background

Tags: java, android, service, background-process

I have been trying to make an alarm application. I have been struggling with making a full screen notification. I finally did manage to do it, but it only works when the app is running in the background.

It also needs to work when you have closed the app. I don't understand what I am supposed to do to achieve this. I know it is possible because my alarm clock app I use every day is able to do this.

Mainactivity.java

```
package com.example.wekkerapp;
import java.util.Calendar;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel";
    static final String FULL_SCREEN_ACTION = "full_screen_action";
    static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

    private void createNotificationChannel() {
        // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
        // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CharSequence name = "Alarm";
            String description = "Het alarm gaat";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("2", name, importance);
            channel.setDescription(description);
            // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
            // or other notification behaviors after this
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(this.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        createNotificationChannel(this);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final TimePicker klok = findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
        klok.setIs24HourView(true);
        final Button getTimeBtn = findViewById(R.id.getTimeBtn);
        final TextView showText = findViewById(R.id.showText);

        final AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);


        getTimeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(FULL_SCREEN_ACTION, null, getApplicationContext(), WekkerService.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                int uur = klok.getHour();
                int minuut = klok.getMinute();
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, uur);
                cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minuut);
                cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
                Toast.makeText(getApplication().getApplicationContext(), "Alarm gaat om " + uur + ":" + minuut,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);


                showText.setText(Integer.toString(uur) + ':' + Integer.toString(minuut));
                NotificationManagerCompat.from(getApplicationContext()).cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);

            }
        });


    }

    static void CreateFullScreenNotification(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity2.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_USER_ACTION | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                        .setContentTitle("Alarm")
                        .setContentText("Het alarm gaat")
                        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                        .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_ALARM)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                        .setFullScreenIntent(pendingIntent, true);
        NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
    }

    private static void createNotificationChannel(Context context) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);

            if (notificationManager.getNotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID) == null) {
                NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "channel_name", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
                channel.setDescription("channel_description");
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Wekkerservice.java

```
package com.example.wekkerapp;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class WekkerService extends IntentService {

    public static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    public WekkerService() {
        super("WekkerService");

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate(); // if you override onCreate(), make sure to call super().
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
        Log.d("test", "onHandleIntent: ");
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.alarmpie);
        if (MainActivity.FULL_SCREEN_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction()))

            mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        mediaPlayer.start(); // no need to call prepare(); create() does that for you
        MainActivity.CreateFullScreenNotification(getApplicationContext());

    }
}
```

Mainactivity2.java

```
package com.example.wekkerapp;

import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        Button stopbutton = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        stopbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                WekkerService.mediaPlayer.stop();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use a BroadcastReceiver and then start the service from its onReceive method.
So in your MainActivity's onClick listener you should change the following pending intent
as follows:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

to

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

and the intent you pass in should launch a BroadcastReceiver.
Immediately after the BroadcastReceiver is launched by the alarm manager, you should start the service from its onReceive method.

Remember that due to the recent changes the OS won't just let you start a service or background service just whenever and however you want!

If the app is closed and you want to start the service, you SHOULD start it as a ForgroundService and show a notification(you have 5 seconds to make this call) otherwise it will throw RemoteServiceException and that's why the code in your service will not run.

I highly encourage you to take a look at this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56471104/9023032
Here is also another useful answer which might become handy:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54035247/9023032